# Disallow segmented control segment from changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I've got a bit of a weird question for a temporary fix we're putting into our app. For terrible reasons, we have a segmented control with three segments, but we have three instances of each segmented control inside of three tableView data sources (don't ask, we're hoping this isn't the final solution...)

Anyway, because of this awful setup, when we select a new segment, instance A of the segmented control gets it's new index selected. We then swap out data sources and call `reloadData` on the table. Now we have instance B of the segmented control with the same index as instance A selected. When we then select the original segment, instance B gets its index set to the new index, and we now reload data, which causes instance A to be shown. Instance A, however, still has the old index selected, and so it's selection shows the wrong index.

I'm currently solving this by manually resetting the selected index in the delegate callback for a tap. However, what would be ideal, would be to tell the segmented control that I don't want it to change it's selection, but I do still want users to be able to interact with it. Is that possible at all? I realize this is a terrible solution, again, we hope to change it in the future, so for now, any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 1):

In the final step, when instance A of the segmented control gets shown again, you should write your cellForRowAtIndexPath to set the segment to the desired segment using the `selectedSegmentIndex` property. That way when instance A is displayed again it will show the correct index.

Comment: I've got something very similar going on right now, after I do all of the fetching for new data, I set the segment back to the correct segment. However, this feels hacky, which isn't the worse thing in the world, since having the segmented control as a cell is a hack in the first place, but I'd like to try to keep the "hackiness" of this fix to a minimum if possible.

Comment: It sounds like the "hacky" ship sailed a long time ago. Now you're just trying to make the mess you have perform correctly.